# how can I link selected to active nodes using the slot numbers

Tags: node-editor, add-on

I would like to create a script which links selected to active nodes based on the slot numbers where slot 0 output on the selected node would link to the slot 0 input of the active node, slot 1 output on the selected node would link to the slot 1 input of the active node etc. I would like this to work on any nodes which are selected and active. underneath I've attached a image of me trying (and failing). any help would be appreciated. thanks
[image]

Comment: Is is part of an operator called from the node editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to locate the [node tree](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeTree.html).  Then you have to find the two nodes you want to connect.  Then for each pair consisting of an output node of the first node and an input node of the second node you have to create a new [Node Link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink) and add it to the node tree.

Here is source code that will give you a start. It's an example using a material.  You can do something similar with compositor nodes or geometry nodes; you just need different code to identify the node tree.  Other than those two lines the rest would be the same. (See below for Geometry Nodes and the compositor)

```py
import bpy

material = bpy.data.materials["Material"]

node_tree = material.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes

dst = nodes.active

srcs = [node for node in nodes if node != dst and node.select]
src = srcs[0]

node_tree.links

node_tree.links.new(src.outputs[0], dst.inputs[0])
```

The `nodes` member of the node tree maintains the *active* node.  You should probably check to make sure it's not `None`, but I didn't.

There is no list of selected nodes.  You have to walk the tree and check the `select` property of each node.  That's what the line starting `srcs =` does.  The active node is also a selected node, so the if clause of the list comprehension also checks to exclude it.

There are two other issues you might want to deal with.  The first is obvious in how I found the `src`: What to do if there is more than one selected node besides the active node.  You'll have to address that according to your needs.

There other has to do with the last statement.  In your example you would put that in a loop like this:

```py
for i in range(len(src.outputs)):
    node_tree.links.new(src.outputs[i], dst.inputs[i])
```

but that leaves you with the question of what to do with mismatched nodes.  Node wrangler puts a lot of effort into figuring this out based on the types of the inputs and outputs; but in the end even it punts to the user a lot of the time.

For geometry nodes, you need to find an object that has a geometry nodes modifier, find the modifier, and the field is called `node_group` instead of `node_tree` (because GN encloses the tree between group input and group output nodes).  Here's an example that assumes the active object has a GN modifier with the default name:

```py
obj = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
node_tree = modifier.node_group
```

For the compositor you should check to see if it is using nodes but the tree is easy to find:

```py
assert(bpy.context.scene.use_nodes == True)
node_tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
```